# Why scanning an index backwards is slower?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

Empirical tests show that a query like this on an InnoDB table:

```
SELECT indexed_column FROM tab ORDER BY indexes_column ASC;
```

is faster than its counterpart with `ORDER BY ... DESC`. Why is this the case?

Note: I did the tests with MySQL 5.7 and 5.6. So this has nothing to do with ascending indexes in 8.0.

Comment: When you say faster, can you give us exact numbers?

Comment: A professional benchmark would be beyond my purpose. Running 1000 times `SELECT col_name FROM t ORDER BY col_name [DESC]` (col_name being timestamp without NULLs) I observe a difference: avg 4.8 real time vs avg 5.2. But running the test yourself is trivial and you'll be able to check al factors that in your opinion could be relevant...

Comment: This post seems to be based on a more serious benchmark than mine. Not sure why a covering index is not used, however you can see that backward index scan is slower: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-descending-indexes-in-mysql/

Comment: A comment (by the author) in the linked article explains: *"Thanks for showing interest in the new feature. The ~15% cost benefit in forward scans can be attributed to the optimizations done in innodb to favor forward scans over backward scans.
For ex:
W.r.t a scan within the page – The records in a page form a singly linked list. To get the next record, a forward scan just follows the link where as the backward scan need to start from the beginning(first slot) till the current slot/record to identify the previous record. ..."*

Comment: *"... Along with the above, there are some more contributing factors like, during page switch – page latching rules currently defined in innodb favor forward scans over backward scans."*"*

Comment: True. Somehow I never suspected this, despite it is shown clearly in Jeremy Cole's InnoDB diagrams: https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_diagrams/blob/master/images/InnoDB_Structures/B%2BTree%20Detailed%20Page%20Structure.png

Comment: The second statement you quoted is much less clear to me honestly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author, Chaithra Gopalareddy,  of the related article, [MySQL 8.0 Labs – Descending Indexes in MySQL](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-descending-indexes-in-mysql/), explains in a comment why backwards index scans are slightly less efficient than forward scans:

> Thanks for showing interest in the new feature. The **~15% cost benefit** **in forward scans** can be attributed to the **optimizations done in innodb to favor forward scans over backward scans**.
>
> For ex: W.r.t a scan within the page – The **records in a page form a singly linked list**. To get the next record, a forward scan just follows the link where as the backward scan need to start from the beginning (first slot) till the current slot/record to identify the previous record.
>
> Along with the above, there are some more contributing factors like, during page switch – **page latching rules currently defined in innodb favor forward scans** over backward scans.

So there are two factors:

- the **single** linked list structure of records inside a page
- page latching rules regarding page switches